# How can I authenticate Google user's ID token in a .NET framework 2.0 website?

Tags: google-api, .net-2.0, google-api-dotnet-client

I have successfully implemented Google login on the client side. My next step would be to validate the user's ID token on the backend.

As advised by [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth), it is recommended that I use the [Google API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/). However, my company is creating the website using .NET framework 2.0, [which is not currently supported](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/) (v1.9.2).

Running `Install-Package Google.Apis` in my Package Manager Console gives me the following error:
`Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework, Version=v2.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.`

What are my options? Are there other ways I can authenticate the ID token or use the Google API Client Library?

Comment: Consider having a Login server for your application that handles the login process. That server could run the latest .NET Framework.

The only other way is to code the Login part of the application using the Google OAUTH2 HTTP/REST protocol rather than using the .NET Framework. See [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is you cant. The current version of the Google .net client library only supports .net Framework 4.0 and 4.5.  You will either have to use that or code it all yourself.

Oauth2 and all of the API requests are simple HTTP posts and HTTP GETS so it is not as hard as you would think to code it from the ground up.  using .Net Framework 2.0.

**Step 1 request authentication: (HTTP GET)**

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code

**step 2 Authorize application  (HTTP POST)**

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
>   code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code

**step 3 Refresh Refreshtoke (HTTP post)**

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
>   client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token

Code ripped from [Google 3 legged oauth2](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/) flow tutorial.